# Como acessar componentes da view que estão dentro de uma ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, view, xamarin-forms

Preciso acessar as propriedades dos componentes criados na `View` para definir alguns valores (exemplo altura e largura), porém estão dentro de uma `ListView`, com isso, no `.cs` eu não consigo dar o This.Componente mesmo com o `x:Name`.

Tentei desta forma, porém não funcionou:

```
var stkEditarEndereco = this.FindByName<StackLayout>("stkEditarEndereco");
```

Como posso resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar no **Xamarin.Forms** os componentes criados no arquivo XAML, você deve setar a propriedade x:Name, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
<ListView x:Name="DemoListView" />
```

Para alterar suas propriedades no code behind (.cs), informe os seguintes dados:

```
DemoListView.RowHeight = 100;
```

Maiores informações: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Necessite de alguma ajuda?

Estou a disposição.

Comment: já fiz isso amigo, só que os componentes que estão dentro da ListView não deixa puxar pelo x:Name

Comment: O que especificamente você necessita alterar?
Tem o xaml do arquivo para postar ?

Possivelmente a melhor solução seria implementar tudo via code cs.

Comment: Eu preciso alterar a imagem de um botão que está dentro da ListView, porém ele não deixa eu acessar mesmo com o x:Name. Sabe algum outro jeito ?

Comment: Veja esse post que respondi.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175651/definir-imagem-para-bot%C3%A3o-dentro-de-listview-xamarin-forms/175767#175767

Existe a opção de criar ResourceDictionary para a imagem, mas lembre-se que é necessário informar o path para cada plataforma no caso do Xamarin.Forms.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/

Answer (score 0):

Para alterar tamanhos dos componentes você pode usas as propriedades do XAML como HeightRequest e WidhRequest.

Mas caso haja a necessidade de alterar ou realizar alguma coisa no code behind você pode criar um CustomCell Para listView Veja[aqui](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/viewcell/)!

Comment: Já estou usando o heightRequest e WidthRequest, porém em um determinado tempo eu preciso que essas propriedades sejam alteradas, e com isso preciso que isso seja feito no code behind. Porém, quando tento pegar o controle com o x:Name ele não deixa por estar dentro da ListView.

Comment: Nesse caso recomendo criar uma contentView . realizar toda a programação que você precisa e colocar ela no controle.
Posta aqui como esta sua ListView eu dou um exemplo mais Claro

Answer (score 0):

não seria melhor utilizar o conceito de Styles para definir esse tipo de propriedade ? dessa forma você pode até mesmo reaproveitar seu layout.

Por exemplo, em meu app tenho um listview que preciso de um layout especifico, com o style ficou dessa forma:

```
<Style x:Key="listGroup" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource Snow}" />
    <Setter Property="IsGroupingEnabled" Value="True"/>
  </Style>
```

No listView ficou assim:

```
<ListView
  Style="{DynamicResource listGroup}"
  GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
  GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding ListaFiltro}" SeparatorVisibility="None"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPedido}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid Padding="5">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation">

          </Label>
          <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Parceiro.CardName}" Font="Small" TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>

        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

O trecho importante aqui é o Style="{DynamicResource listGroup}" .

Esse exemplo é no listview direto, mas dependendo do controle dentro da sua listview você poderá fazer um style especifico para ele.

Comment: é que o que acontece é o seguinte, eu criei a listview normal, e dentro das celulas dela tem um frame com um stacklayout dentro, e dentro do stacklayout um image button. Esse image button está ficando com o tamanho diferente em cada versão do android, marshmallow, lollipop e kitkat. Em uma outra view, eu fiz uma verificação antes pra saber qual é a versão do android e atribuir a imagem certa pro botão conforme essa versão. E é isso que eu queria tentar fazer nessa View que contem a ListView