# Definir imagem para botão dentro de ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, button, xamarin-forms

Como definir outra imagem para um `Button` que está dentro de uma `ListView` pelo .cs ou na `ViewModel` ?
Não consigo acessar esse `Button` no .cs por estar dentro da `ListView`.

No meu xaml, o botão já possui uma imagem, porém em um determinado trecho do código ele precisa atribuir outra imagem.

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="btnEditar" BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
        Image="editar.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" 
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditarCommand, 
    Source={x:Reference MeusEnderecosView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

Já tentei dessa forma no .cs:

```
var btnEditar = this.FindByName<Button>("btnEditar");
btnEditar.Image = "editar2.png";
```

Porém da erro de objeto não existente.

Como posso resolver isso ?

Comment: A imagem `editar.png` (especificamente Android) está na pasta adequada? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/. As vezes é necessário `clean`, `rebuild` no projeto.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow está sim, já dei clean e rebuild varias vezes e não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver este cenário, você pode implementar um IValueConverter, que será responsável de validar e exibir sua imagem de acordo com a regra desejada, e exibindo as imagens de acordo com os devices.

Neste exemplo que criei eu implementei um projeto simples, aonde a regra está  baseada no nome que vem do Binding, mais, você é livre para implementar a regra como desejar.

Segue o código:

Arquivo ConverterValue

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XFlImageButtonListView.Converter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Método responsável em Exibir icone no botão, através de uma regra de negócio
    /// </summary>
    public class ImageViewConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Valida regra de negócio para exibir imagem no botão
            if(value.ToString().Equals("Nome1"))
                //Exibe imagem para cada platforma.
                return Device.OnPlatform<String>("callanswerIOS.png", "callanswer.png", "img/callanswerUWP.png");
            else
                //Exibe imagem para cada platforma.
                return Device.OnPlatform<String>("pointingdownIOS.png", "pointingdown.png", "img/pointingdownUWP.png");

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Volta a imagem padrão para cada platforma.
            return Device.OnPlatform<String>("pointingdownIOS.png", "pointingdown.png", "img/pointingdownUWP.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Arquivo XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XFlImageButtonListView"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:XFlImageButtonListView.Converter"
             x:Class="XFlImageButtonListView.MainPage">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converter:ImageViewConverter x:Key="imgConvert"></converter:ImageViewConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="50">

      <ListView x:Name="lstPalestrantes"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Palestrantes}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <Button Text="{Binding Nome}" Image="{Binding Nome, Converter={StaticResource imgConvert}}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>


    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Criei uma solução no github para isto, se quiser saber maiores detalhes:
https://github.com/juniorporfirio/XFlImageButtonListView

Espero ter ajudado.

Dúvidas, estou a disposição.